# Python email sending keeps adding new attachments

Tags: python, mime-message

I'm sending customized emails to the people from an email list I took from an Excel sheet.

I have used `MIMEMultipart` to send the email and attachment, and first person is getting the mail properly.

The second person is getting mail with the messages of the first person as well as their own. The third person is getting the message of first two as well as theirs.

This and goes on, each time adding another message to the mail. How do I reset the `MIMEMultipart` after sending a single mail in python? My code is below:

```py
for i in range(len(emails)):
    name = names[i] + ","
    email = emails[i] + "@nmamit.in"
    TEXT = "my message" + name
    msg['Subject'] = subjet_txt
    msg['From'] = your_email
    msg['To'] = email
    msg.attach(MIMEText(TEXT, 'plain'))
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(your_email, email, text)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating a *new* message in each iteration, it (`msg`) appears to have been created *before* the loop starts. That means the line:

```py
msg.attach(MIMEText(TEXT, 'plain'))
```

will attach *another* copy of the `TEXT` each time through the loop, to the already-existing message.

The solution is to start with a *fresh* message each time, such as with:

```py
for i in range(len(emails)):
    message = MIMEMultipart()  # Fresh message for each iteration.
    name = names[i] + ","      # Remainder of code as per current.
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank youu SOLVED!!